# Multiple File Upload with HTML 5 and PHP

Tags: php, upload

I'm trying to upload multiple files and attach them to Wordpress post.
This code works great with single images:

**PHP**

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        return $attach_id;
}

if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="images">
    <label for="images">Images</label>
    <input type="file" name="images" id="images" tabindex="25"/>
</fieldset>
```

But how can I make it work with multiple images?

I do know I have to add `multiple="multiple"` to the input, the name of the input should be `images[]`. But I definately have problems with PHP script.

Comment: [Uploading multiple files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: Thank you for the reference, @Akam. However I would highly appreciate if you could demonstrate how I can adopt it to my PHP part.

Comment: its better to use multiple <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" tabindex="25"/> instead of using HTML5 multiple feature because currently its not cross compatible.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Akam. But I would like to stick to HTML5.

Comment: @SergeySedykh — The ability to have multiple inputs with the same name has not been removed in HTML 5.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks, but I don't want to have multiple inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone will need this in future: I found the solution [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50379/uploading-multiple-attachments-from-front-end-with-a-description):

```
// If we have files
if ( $_FILES )
{
    // Get the upload attachment files
    $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];

    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($files['name'][$key])
        {
            $file = array(
                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
            );

            $_FILES = array("upload_attachment" => $file);

            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array)
            {
                $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post->ID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```